# Optimizing Jetpack for Wordpress

Tags: cache, performance, plugin-jetpack

Yslow reports following issues with Jetpack:

1) Compress http://stats.wordpress.com/e-201219.js using gzip

2) Configure etags for http://stats.wordpress.com/g.gif?...

Modified the format so that it is easier to understand. How can I take action against these items. I am already using latest version of W3 Total cache plugin.

Pls advise.

Comment: Close-voted as **off topic**. This question involves optimizing an arbitrary, third-party script/API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't "optimize" Jetpack. Look at the URL; it's served from wordpress.com. You get what they offer from their servers.